# Delete as few as possible digits to make number divisible by 3

Tags: string, algorithm, biginteger

I was solving this question, namely we have given number *N*, which can be very big, it can have up to 100000 digits.

Now I want to know what is the most efficient way to find those digits, and I think that in big numbers I will need to delete at most 3 digits to make the number divisible by 3.

I know that number is divisible by three if the sum of its digits is divisible by three, but I can't think of how can we use this.

My idea is to brute force over the string and to check if we delete that digit is the number going to be divisible by 3, but my solution fails at complex examples. Please give me some hints.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: At most 3 digits?  Counter example: 1000000000000. How many digits do you want to delete to make it divisible by 3?

Comment: Another example: 199999999999999. Can't be reduced to make it divisible by 3.

Answer (score 6):

If the sum of the digits modulo 3 is equal to 1, you want to delete a single 1, 4, or 7. If the sum of the digits is 2, you want to delete a single 2, 5, or 8.

If that can't be done, then you have to delete two digits.

To avoid scanning the list twice, you could remember the indices of up to two digits congruent to 1, and the indices of up to two digits congruent to 2, so when you compute the final modulus you know where to look.

Comment: Hmm, good idea, and if the sum of the digits modulo 3 is equal to 1, we want to delete digits that sum up to 1, 4,7,11,14,16.. right?

Comment: Yes the sum of deleted digits mod 3 has to be equal to the cross sum mod 3. So for mod 3 = 1 it can be either a digit which mod 3 is also 1 or two digits where both mod 3 = 2, because (2 + 2) % 3 = 1. And vice versa for mod 3 = 2.

Answer (score 0):

The number 3 has some special properties relative to a base-10 number system that you can leverage.

10 is 1 more than 9, and 9 is evenly divisible by 3, so the "1" in "10" acts as a sort of remainder from adding 1 to 9. As a result, if the sum of all digits in the number is evenly divisible by 3 then that number is also divisible by 3.

So if you begin by figuring out what the [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) is after adding all the digits, then you'll know whether the number is divisible by zero (i.e. results in a modulo zero) or not. If not, then you can subtract one digit at a time, recalculating the modulo of the resulting number until you end up with a modulo of zero.

Comment: Thank you for writing, but I already knew this, I just edited my post.

Comment: Do you want to say that if number N mod 3 = 2 we want to delete the digits whose sum (A1+A2+A3+...+AQ) mod 3 = 2 and with this we will make the number divisible by three?

Comment: @someone123123: Yeah, from your description it's difficult to tell whether you have discretion over which digits to remove (e.g. if the digits must be deleted from the right of the number or something), and whether you need to say which digits you'd remove, or just how many would be necessary. But you've got the right idea. If you can remove arbitrary digits, then an input whose sum mod 3 is 2 would require 1 digit to be removed whose mod 3 is 2, or two digits to be removed otherwise.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: What about a number like 19999999999999999? Remainder is 1, but no matter how many digits you take away, it is not divisible by 3 (because the mod 3 will always be 1).

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: As I suggested in my earlier comment, if the problem statement allows you to remove any digit you want, then remove the one digit with a remainder of 1 (i.e. `1`). This would leave you with `9999999999999999`, which is evenly divisible by 3. If you must remove digits from the right, then you'll have to remove all the digits until you remove the `1`, leaving `0`, which is also evenly divisible by 3.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: If you can remove *any* digit, it could work (but still not always). But, when removing from the right, removing the final 1 would leave nothing, not 0. There is no 0 there.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: I feel like you're being pedantic. `1` is mathematically the same as `...0000001`. The zero is implied. If you're representing the number as a string of characters, then removing all of the "digits" will leave an empty string, and the programmer will have to be smart enough to add back a zero in this corner case. But most numeric representations in computer code will automatically consider "nothing" to mean "0". If the OP is unsure, he should clarify how his prof wants the program to respond in these corner cases. My answer is as correct as can be with the information given.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: Yes, I am being pedantic. I am adhering to the question.

Answer (score -1):

You should check what makes a number divisible by 3. If you find it you should divide the problem into smaller problems

Comment: I know that one number is divisible by 3 only if the sum of its digits is divisible by three, we can find the sum for the whole number and then divide it into sub-problems, but how can we solve those sub-problems is what i can't think of.

Comment: Tell me what you think the sub-problems are

Comment: We can say that if we have the whole number, we can split it in two parts and see if those parts are divisible by three if they are then we can see that the whole number is going to be, but this is not going to work always, I'm thinking of that is there math proof that we will have to delete at most 2 or 3 digits.

Comment: So yes you are in the right path you are trying to take out at max 3 numbers that will change the sum to a multiple of 3. So lets say your total is N and its N = 3k + M. so out of all the digits you have that are not a multiple of 3 you are trying to find at max 3 digits that sum up to M

Comment: It doesn't look hard to find those three digits, but are we sure that there will be at most 3 digits that will sum up to M